# C# / WPF - CurrentDispatcher and DispatchTimer - Very infrequency Concurrent Modification exeception

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I have a WPF GUI that throws a specific error perhaps once a day.

```
“Collection was modified after the enumerator was Instantiated"
```

The specific collection to which it's referring is a Dictionary of TimeStamps. 'dict' is a private member variable.

```
dict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
```

There are two places where the Collection is referenced, both **should** only be called on the dispatch thread. The first location is for adding to the dictionary and is called when a specific DependencyProperty on a ViewModel changes,

```
void CalledFromDispatch(Item i)
{
   dict[i.Category].Add(DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

The second place is where I read from the Dictionary. Outstanding is a bool dependency property.

```
void PeriodicUpdate()
{
    HasOutstanding = dict["New"].Any(); 
}
```

The Assignment to `HasOutstanding` is where the exception is thrown, I know I could use `Count > 0` to solve the problem but it worries me that the exception is possible.

The first piece of code is called, in effect, like this;

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, () => CalledFromDispatch(i));
```

The second is scheduled like this;

```
DispatcherTimer DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.DataBind)
DispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
DispatcherTimer.Start();
  ...
DispatcherTimer.Tick += (s, e) => PeriodicUpdate();
```

So my questions boil down to;

- Does the DispatchTimer use the same thread as the CurrentDispatcher?
- If so, is it possible that the Dispatcher might switch out a scheduled operation mid execution?

Otherwise I don't know how this occurs.

I'd really love to learn more about how the DispatchTimer interacts with the CurrentDispatcher. If anyone has a resource which might help clarify the situation then I'd greatly appreciate the link.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that both of these were called/setup on the UI thread, it should be fine.

My suspicion is that you're using `BeginInvoke` incorrectly.  [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx) is the `Dispatcher` for "the thread currently executing", **not** the UI thread's Dispatcher.  You most likely need to change this to something like `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (the Dispatcher associated with the current Application), or some UIElement's Dispatcher.